# Homotopy coherence for a $ A_{\infty }$ space

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, operads

This question came up when I read german article about [operads](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operade#Anwendungen_in_der_Topologie) in topology & homotopy theory. translated to english the statement is:

a $ A_{\infty }$ space is a topological space $Y$ with a *homotopy coherent* set of maps

$${\displaystyle f_{n}:K_{n}\times Y^{n}\to Y}$$

so that $Y$ is a algebra over the (non symetrical) operad $ K = \{ K_n \}$.

The [associahedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associahedron) $K_n$ are convex polytopes in which each vertex corresponds to a possible way correctly inserting opening and closing parentheses in a word of $n$ letters and the edges correspond to single application of the associativity rule for $n$ arguments.

**Question**: what means a *homotopy coherent* set of maps?

I thought that the edges between vertices of $K_n$ represent the homotopies between different ways to place the parentheses. so what extra data is given by *homotopy coherentce* of the maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn’t a very precise statement. What’s actually meant is that $Y$ is given a structure of an algebra over an operad over the $A^\infty$ operad. So the maps $K_n\times Y^n\to Y$ must be compatible with the various maps $K_m\to K_n$ that are part of the operad structure, such as the vertices $K_2\rightrightarrows K_n$ defining the parenthesizations.

Comment: what you you mean by "the vertices $K_2\rightrightarrows K_n$ defining the parenthesizations..."? I thought that that each 'naive' vertex of for example $K_4$ represents such parenthesization, namely as given here: https://nilesjohnson.net/associahedra.html I still not understand how such maps $K_2\rightrightarrows K_n$ "define" the paranthesizations. how do they look like for example in case $K_2\rightrightarrows K_4$?

Comment: Well, $K_2$ is a point, so there are five maps $K_2\to K_4$, one for each vertex.

Comment: oh yes, of course, sorry for stupid question